# PDF file getting stripped from iPhone MFMailComposeViewController call

Tags: iphone, email, pdf

My PDF file appears in both UIWebView and the mail on screen on iphone as an attachment.  When I send it to my email (using two different email carriers) it gets stripped out-no file attachment.  I can send pdfs to these email accounts on my iphone and forward them ok  so I don't think its my email provider but iOS that is stripping the file out???  I can attach images ok but NOT PDF files.  Not sure where the issue is and how to find where the issue is occuring.  Thanks!

My code:

```
-(void)doSendEmail :(NSString *)use_email :(NSString *)amsg {
    if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {
        MFMailComposeViewController* controller = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
        controller.mailComposeDelegate = self;
        [controller setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:use_email, nil]];

            NSString *filen=self.filepath1;
            NSString *pdfPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:filen ofType:@"pdf"];
            NSData *pdfData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:pdfPath];
            [controller addAttachmentData:pdfData mimeType:@"application/pdf" fileName:self.filename1]
        }


    //Set messages
    [controller setSubject:self.subject];
    [controller setMessageBody:amsg isHTML:NO];

    //Display email for user to send
    [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
    [controller release];
}

-(void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller  
          didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result 
                        error:(NSError*)error {
    if ( (result == MFMailComposeResultSent) && (stat==4) ) {
        billsent=1;
    }
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but I came across it in my google searches so I thought I'd post my solution:

It is likely that your `pdfPath` is wrong.  If the pdf is loaded as an attachment properly you should **not** see an icon for the attachment.  Instead you will see a large image of the pdf itself.

If you set a break point right after `NSData *pdfData =` and hover over pdfData it will probably show you that it is nil with 0 bytes of data.